What is the most efficient algorithm to check for valid word placements on a game board and trigger Game Over if no valid moves are available?
What are the details of your problem?
I'm developing a Scrabble-like game and need to implement an algorithm that triggers the Game Over state when no player can place a valid word using their available tiles on the open slots of the board. The game involves multiple players who each have tiles they can place on the board.
The specific problem involves determining whether a player's available tiles can form a valid word in any of the open (empty) positions on the board. If no valid word can be formed, the game ends, and the winner is determined.
My Concerns:

Prefix Words: Words that can be extended by adding tiles to the beginning of existing words on the board.

Suffix Words: Words that can be extended by adding tiles to the end of existing words.

Infix Words: Words that can be formed by placing tiles in the middle of open spaces between existing letters.

Efficiency: The algorithm must run during each player's turn, and looping through all possible tiles and word combinations could take too long. It needs to check all possible words quickly without causing delays during gameplay.


The problem I'm facing:

The algorithm I currently use either does not correctly detect all possible word placements or it takes too long to execute, especially during each player's turn.
I might be overcomplicating the problem or missing a more efficient solution.

What I need help with:

Hints or alternative approaches to efficiently determine valid word placements (considering prefix, suffix, and infix cases).
Suggestions on optimizing the algorithm to ensure fast performance during the turn-based game cycle.

What did you try, and what were you expecting?
I’ve implemented a recursive Boolean method to check if any valid moves are available on the Scrabble-like game board. The function goes through each player’s tiles and tries to find possible word placements on the board by examining valid tiles and open neighboring tiles. The idea is that, during a player’s turn, the algorithm should identify whether it's possible to form a valid word using the available tiles.
My expectations:
I expected the algorithm to correctly identify when a valid word can be formed and return true.
If no valid words can be created, the method should return false, signaling that the game may need to end or the player has no valid moves left.
What’s actually happening:
I keep getting false returns, indicating no valid moves, even when there should be valid moves available. The Debug.Log messages consistently state "No Valid Word Found," and the game proceeds as if no words can be formed, which is incorrect.
I suspect that I'm either missing some valid word placements or that the recursive nature of the algorithm is not exploring all possibilities as expected.
Here’s the code I’ve been using:
The method first checks each player’s tiles, goes through all valid board tiles, and tries to place tiles in neighboring positions to form valid words:
void OnSubmit()
{
    if (AnyValidMovesAvailable(board))
    {
        Debug.Log("Valid Moves Available");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("No Valid Moves Available");
    }
}
public bool AnyValidMovesAvailable(Board board)
{
    // Create Unplaced Potential Letters using the remaining Unplaced Tiles
    foreach (var playerInfo in PlayerInfoManager.Instance.GetAllPlayerInfos())
    {
        List<PotentialLetter> unPlacedPotentialLetters = playerInfo.GetPlayerTiles()
           .Select(tile => new PotentialLetter(tile, false))
           .ToList();

        List<PotentialLetter> potentialWord = new List<PotentialLetter>();

        // Loop through all the valid tiles on the board to check possible word placements
        foreach (var validTiles in wordValidator.GetValidTiles())
        {
            foreach (var validTile in validTiles.GetValidTiles())
            {
                BoardTile boardTile = validTile.tileProperties.boardTile;

                // Check if a valid word can be placed starting from this tile
                if (moveAvailabilityChecker.PossibleValidMoves(board, boardTile, potentialWord, unPlacedPotentialLetters, wordValidator))
                {
                    Debug.Log("There is a Valid Word");
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("No Valid Word Found");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // If no valid word was found, return false
    return false;
}

public bool PossibleValidMoves(Board board, BoardTile validBoardTile, List<PotentialLetter> potentialValidWord, List<PotentialLetter> unPlacedPotentialLetters, WordValidator wordValidator)
{
    WordEvaluation wordEvaluation = new WordEvaluation();
    Tile validTile = validBoardTile.GetTile();

    // Add the Valid Tile as a Potential Letter (first tile)
    if (potentialValidWord.Count == 0)
    {
        PotentialLetter potentialLetter = new PotentialLetter(validTile, true);
        potentialValidWord.Add(potentialLetter);
    }

    // Perform an Order using the Position on the board (sorts potential word)
    OrderPotentialWord(potentialValidWord);

    // Get neighboring board tiles (prefix, infix, suffix positions)
    List<BoardTile> neighborBoardTiles = board.GetNeighboringBoardTiles(validBoardTile);

    // Loop over all possible neighboring tiles
    foreach (var neighborBoardTile in neighborBoardTiles)
    {
        // Skip if the neighboring tile already has an unplaced tile
        if (!neighborBoardTile.HasUnPlacedTile())
        {
            foreach (var unPlacedPotentialLetter in unPlacedPotentialLetters)
            {
                // Ensure valid letter placement (skip invalid placements if needed)
                if (!IsValidPlacement(potentialValidWord.Last(), unPlacedPotentialLetter))
                {
                    continue;  // Skip invalid placements
                }

                // Place the letter temporarily in the neighbor tile
                neighborBoardTile.SetUnPlacedTile(unPlacedPotentialLetter.tile);
                unPlacedPotentialLetter.possiblePosition = neighborBoardTile.GetBoardPosition();

                // Create new potential word and update remaining unplaced letters
                List<PotentialLetter> newPotentialWord = new List<PotentialLetter>(potentialValidWord) { unPlacedPotentialLetter };
                List<PotentialLetter> newRemainingUnplacedLetters = new List<PotentialLetter>(unPlacedPotentialLetters);
                newRemainingUnplacedLetters.Remove(unPlacedPotentialLetter);

                // Check if the current word could already be valid before recursion
                if (IsValidWordSoFar(newPotentialWord, wordEvaluation))
                {
                    // If valid, return true and stop further exploration
                    Debug.Log($"Valid word found: {string.Join("", newPotentialWord.Select(e => e.value))}");
                    return true;
                }

                // Recursively search from this new neighbor (DFS)
                if (PossibleValidMoves(board, neighborBoardTile, newPotentialWord, newRemainingUnplacedLetters, wordValidator))
                {
                    return true;
                }

                // Backtrack: reset the neighbor and remove the last letter added
                neighborBoardTile.SetUnPlacedTile(null);
                newPotentialWord.RemoveAt(newPotentialWord.Count - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    // Construct the word string after exploring all neighbors
    string possibleWordString = string.Join("", potentialValidWord.Select(e => e.value));

    // Base case: if the word is valid, return true
    if (wordValidator.IsValidWord(possibleWordString))
    {
        Debug.Log($"Valid word found: {possibleWordString}");
        return true;
    }

    // No valid word found
    return false;
}



Not sure about specific algorithms.. but I guess you could at least cache previous words in order to not recheck all possible words from scratch but rather only the ones that were previously possible at all .. depends of course what exactly changes between player turns (e.g. if new letters come into play or stay the same from the beginning)

You may want to take a look at this paper: https://users.cs.northwestern.edu/~robby/uc-courses/22001-2008-winter/faster-scrabble-gordon.pdf

@PaulCarlton This really helped. I might have a guide now. Possibly using GADDAG algorithm as the suited solution. Thanks

Glad to hear.  Since you're working in C#, it would probably be best to break out that code into a module or stand alone solution that you can run unit tests against.  Once you've got some kind of implementation going, you can then start feeding it scenarios and check against those scenarios for the possible outcomes you expect within those scenarios.  That should bolt it down, and then you can take that project of code and bring it into your game.
